# React Native upgrade duplicate symbols issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I aware there are similar questions on here but the answers given are not helping me. So here's my questions specifically.

So Upgrading from 0.57.8 to 0.58.x seems to give me this issue:

```
ld: 32 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My podfile already has solutions recommended on other questions:

I'm totally stuck right now :( p.s I'm using `rn-dif-purge` to upgrade

```
post_install do |installer|
      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
          if target.name == 'yoga'
              # Workaround: react-native v0.52 bug issue #17274
              # node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga/YGNodePrint.cpp:208:46: Implicit conversion loses integer
              # precision: 'size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'const uint32_t' (aka 'const unsigned int')
              # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17274#issuecomment-356363557
              target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                  config.build_settings['GCC_TREAT_WARNINGS_AS_ERRORS'] = 'NO'
                  config.build_settings['GCC_WARN_64_TO_32_BIT_CONVERSION'] = 'NO'
              end
          end
          if target.name == 'react-native-google-maps'
              target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                  config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'No'
              end
          end
          if target.name == "React"
              target.remove_from_project
          end
      end
  end

  target 'myCoolAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end
```

Full output:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React'
duplicate symbol __ZN5folly7dynamic7destroyEv in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZNK5folly7dynamic4hashEv in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZNK5folly7dynamic4sizeEv in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZNK5folly7dynamic8typeNameEv in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN5folly9TypeErrorD2Ev in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN5folly9TypeErrorD1Ev in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN5folly9TypeErrorD0Ev in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN5folly9TypeErrorC2ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEENS_7dynamic4TypeESB_ in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN5folly9TypeErrorC1ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEENS_7dynamic4TypeESB_ in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN5folly7dynamic5eraseENSt3__111__wrap_iterIPKS0_EES5_ in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN5folly7dynamicaSEOS0_ in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZNK5folly7dynamicltERKS0_ in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZNK5folly7dynamiceqERKS0_ in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN5folly7dynamicaSERKS0_ in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZTVN5folly9TypeErrorE in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZTSN5folly9TypeErrorE in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZTIN5folly9TypeErrorE in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN5folly7dynamic8TypeInfoIxE4typeE in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN5folly7dynamic8TypeInfoIdE4typeE in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN5folly7dynamic8TypeInfoIbE4typeE in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN5folly7dynamic8TypeInfoINS0_10ObjectImplEE4typeE in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN5folly7dynamic8TypeInfoINSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEE4typeE in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN5folly7dynamic8TypeInfoINSt3__16vectorIS0_NS2_9allocatorIS0_EEEEE4typeE in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN5folly9TypeErrorC2ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEENS_7dynamic4TypeE in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN5folly9TypeErrorC1ERKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEENS_7dynamic4TypeE in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN5folly7dynamic8typeNameENS0_4TypeE in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN5folly7dynamic8TypeInfoIxE4nameE in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN5folly7dynamic8TypeInfoIdE4nameE in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN5folly7dynamic8TypeInfoIbE4nameE in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN5folly7dynamic8TypeInfoINS0_10ObjectImplEE4nameE in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN5folly7dynamic8TypeInfoINSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEE4nameE in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN5folly7dynamic8TypeInfoINSt3__16vectorIS0_NS2_9allocatorIS0_EEEEE4nameE in:
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly/libFolly.a(dynamic.o)
    /Users/user01/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my-cool-app-efqysosplvdxlnghszhgchphxsac/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReact.a(dynamic.o)
ld: 32 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the project is on Git, Rename the current folder (for example if it is "MyProject", change it to "MyProjectt"), then:

1. Commit all your changes!
2. Create a new project with that name `react-native init MyProject --version=0.58.9`
3. Copy the `.git` folder (note that it's hidden) - also copy all your `.js` files such as `app.js` and `package.json`
4. Install all your dependencies and bump up the `react-native` version too!
5. Run your Git client (for example GitHub desktop) - you see changes in `iOS` and `android` folder
6. Commit changes

Comment: I really want to avoid doing this :)